# How can I get the name type of a parameter at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net

So I have a `MethodInfo` object `m` that I'm testing and I want to extract the type of a parameter. For instance, I want `"int"` and `string` from the following.

```
public void SomeMethod ( int i, string s )
{
   // ... 
}
```

When I run

```
ParameterInfo pinf = m.GetParameters.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "i");
```

then

```
ping.GetType().Name
```

it returns `"RuntimeParameterInfo"`.

So what do I actually need to be doing to get `"int"`?

This is an example I made up, but the idea comes from a unit test I'm writing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ping.ParameterType.Name` instead.

> [**`ParameterInfo.ParameterType` Property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> Gets the Type of this parameter.

Comment: You mean `ParameterType`?

Answer (score 1):

```
ping.ParameterType
```

> Gets the Type of this parameter.